# Dynamically change point/marker on click Openlayers 5

Tags: wordpress, openlayers, openlayers-5

I am having issues trying to implement a dynamic marker in my OpenLayer Map widget. I would like that a marker/point is placed on the map "onclick". Instead of placing a new marker/point each mouse click, I would like the marker to be be refreshed on the new position. I have been trying to find some documentation on the layers/vectors and having difficulties understanding how to refresh/replace the layer...

Here is my current OL code for my map that updates two inputs with the latitude and longitude on mouse click:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
    zoom: 4
    })
    });

map.on('click', function(evt){
    var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    var lon = lonlat[0];
    var lat = lonlat[1];
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = lon;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If your marker is a point feature something like this should do it

```
map.on('click', function(evt){
    myMarker.getGeometry().setCoordinates(evt.coordinates);
});
```