# How to apply a pattern fill style to a multipolygon that returns multiple styles

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, openlayers

**CONTEXT**

I have a vector composed of multi polygons, each one of these have a unique class and I set a style related to it. I currently doing this way:

```js
let multiPolyVector = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource ({
        format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:31982'}),
        url: 'assets/geojson/randomVector.geojson'
    }),
    style: (feature) => {
        let class = feature.get("CLASS");
        switch(class) {
            case "CLASS1":
                return this.styleArea('rgba(240, 240, 240, 1)'); // 
            break;
            case "CLASS2":
                return this.styleArea('rgba(115, 115, 240, 1)'); 
            break;
            case "CLASS3":
                return this.styleArea('rgba(168, 168, 0, 1)'); // 
            break;
            case "CLASS4":
                return this.stylePoint('rgba(255, 255, 115, 1)'); // 
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

The `styleArea()` is a function that returns an OpenLayers style:

```js
styleArea(insideColor:string, exteriorColor:string=insideColor, exteriorWidth=2){
    let area = new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: exteriorColor,
            width: exteriorWidth
        }),
            fill: new Fill({
            color: insideColor
        })
    });
    return area;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Now I trying to create a function that returns an OL's style, but this time as a pattern image. After the help in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59271809/applying-an-image-as-fill-pattern-to-a-polygon-does-not-change-its-style) made by myself I was able to apply the pattern style to a vector, but now I need to apply in a multi polygon vector. If I try the same way as before, all the other styles are rewrited. I tried different solutions and some of them generate the error:

> TypeError: "style.getImage is not a function"

which I think is because the image isn't load yet when it is applied to the style. I believe that if I just declare the vector, then modify the style based on the filtered classes the problem can be solved (don't figured out how to yet), but I really want to return the fill partern as an OL style from a function, so that I can use later on other vectors.

- **Ionic version:** 5.4.9
- **OL version:** 6.1.1

**My latest attempt:**

```
stylePattern(pattern:string) {
    console.log("Function Fired");
    let patternSrc = "assets/images/patterns/" + pattern; // The pattern passed is the name of the PNG file
    let ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    let image = new Image();
    let createdPattern = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');

    image.onload = () => {
        return new Style({
            fill: new Fill({
                color: createdPattern
            })
        });
    };
    image.src = patternSrc;             
}
```

This way I don't receive any errors and I can see the pattern image loaded in Dev Tools, but it wasn't applied to the vector style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style function must return the style, not the onload function.  Due to the asynchronous loading you will need a style cache solution similar to this question [Scaling the icon-image size to an absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492200/scaling-the-icon-image-size-to-an-absolute-value)  You might also want to pass the feature to your stylePattern function to force a rerender when the pattern is set, so the function might look something like this

```
let styleCache = {};

stylePattern(pattern:string, feature) {
    console.log("Function Fired");
    let style = styleCache[pattern];
    if (!style) {
      let ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
      let image = new Image();
      style = new Style({
          fill: new Fill({
            color: 'transparent'
          })
        });
      styleCache[pattern] = style;
      image.onload = () => {
        let createdPattern = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');
        style.getFill().setColor(createdPattern);
        feature.changed();  // force a refresh or just wait until next render?
      }
      let patternSrc = "assets/images/patterns/" + pattern; // The pattern passed is the name of the PNG file
      image.src = patternSrc;
    }
    return style;
}
```